# Смешанная отрисовка моделей

Tags: c++, c, 3d, directx, direct3d

Отрисовываю в Direct3D9 модели. Взял минимальный пример. На фоне плоскость с текстурой, перед ней чайник, созданный функцией dx. Модели отрисовываются друг на друге. Как правильно отрисовать модели,чтобы чайник был именно перед плоскостью, а не наоборот? Код отрисовки:

```
void D3DXDevice::PaintModel()
    {
        if (this->Device)
        {
        Device->Clear(NULL, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, Colors::White, 1, NULL);
        Device->BeginScene();
        Device->SetFVF(Vertex::FVF); // настройки, там текстуры, нормали и прочее
        Device->SetStreamSource(0, this->models, 0, sizeof(Vertex)); 
        // this->model - экземпляр класса модель, (там все, материал, текстур, и т.д.)

       // отрисовываем плоскость

       // сдвигаем мировое преобразование на 20 единиц на нас(по -z) и рисуем чайник
        ID3DXMesh* Teapot;
        D3DXCreateTeapot(Device, &Teapot, 0);
        D3DXMATRIX trans;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&trans, 0.f, 0.f, -20.f);
        Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &trans);
        Teapot->DrawSubset(0);
        Teapot->Release();

        Device->EndScene();
        Device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
}
```

Прикладываю скриншот результата. Какую технику следует применить, чтобы рисовалось все верно(у меня модель, в ней несколько текстур, все это надо рисовать не за раз, а переключая материалы, на скриншоте видно, как модели просвечиваются сквозь друг друга).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Включите Z-тест (он же тест глубины)

Comment: @Kromster ответ на вопрос уже нашёл, дело было в ошибочной матрице перспективной проекции. Z-буфер был включен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неправильно заданная матрица перспективной проекции, перепутаны параметры znear и zrear.